# How to pass a single context parameter for 2 different usage in presenter?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp

so i have this MVP implementation for my app,

myActivity:

```
class ValidateOTPActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ValidateOTPListener {

  private lateinit var presenter: ValidateOTPPresenter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    presenter = ValidateOTPPresenter(this, this)
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

myPresenter:

```
class ValidateOTPPresenter constructor(val context: Context, val listener: ValidateOTPListener) {
...
...
...
}
```

myListener:

```
interface ValidateOTPListener {
    fun onValidationSuccess(response: JSONObject)
    fun onValidationFailed()
}
```

i want to use both Context and ValidateOTPListener in the presenter, how to avoid passing two `this` in `presenter = ValidateOTPPresenter(this, this)` ? i only want to pass one `this`, is it possible ?

Comment: No its not possible, if you are passing 2 arguments than you have you have to receive 2 arguments.

Comment: umm , i mean i currently passing 2 arguments, but is it possible to pass only one argument ? because i pass the same thing  
`presenter = ValidateOTPPresenter(THIS, THIS)` 
can't i just go 
`presenter = ValidateOTPPresenter(THIS)`
and modified 
`class ValidateOTPPresenter constructor(val context: Context) {`

but the thing is i want to use Context , as well as the interface onsuccess + onfailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `Context` to interface inside `ValidateOTPPresenter`

```
class ValidateOTPPresenter constructor(private val context: Context){
    private var listener:ValidateOTPListener? = null
    init{
        if(context is ValidateOTPListener){
           listener = context
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you this is what i'm looking for, followed yours and @p.mathew13's answer. android studio lint the declaration and suggest  `Join declaration and assignment` and this is what i got `var listener: ValidateOTPListener = context as ValidateOTPListener`
it's working now thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this:

```
   class ValidateOTPActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ValidateOTPListener {

      private lateinit var presenter: ValidateOTPPresenter
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        presenter = ValidateOTPPresenter(this)
        ...
        ...
      }
    }
```

Then in your presenter:

```
 class ValidateOTPPresenter constructor(val context: Context) {
  val otpListener:ValidateOTPListener
  init{
    otpListener= context as ValidateOTPListener
   }
...
...
...
}
```